# Showing a facebook app without authorization

Tags: facebook, oauth

im trying to do an app that doesn't require to redirect for authorize.

What i wanted to do is an app that detects if it likes a page it shows some content,
of doesn't like, it shows another kind of content.

How can i do ?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the PHP SDK (or similar). All you have to do is put the app on a Fan Page and decode the `signed_request` parameter and see if the user has liked the page ( `liked =>`1.

You can decode the signed_request by calling: `$facebook->getSignedRequest();` and then `var_dump` it to see the data it returns.